# How do I perform an operation to multiple spreadsheets using "OpenbyID" in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Please bear with me as I'm a newbie, but I have formed a list of the ID's of the spreadsheets that I have in a folder which I have stored on a sheet in 1 column. I am trying to execute a script that will go into each of those spreadsheets and delete sheets of a given name if they are in there. So far this is what I have but I'm not sure where I screwed up:

```
function cleanAllOld () {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('fileList');
  var numberFiles = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i=0; i<numberFiles; i++) {

    try{

// File to be cleaned
  var fileID = sheet.getRange(2+i, 1, numberFiles-1).getValues();


  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i]);
  var sheet1 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of CALC');
  var sheet2 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Print');
  var sheet3 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Markbook');

 if (destination.sheet1 == null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet1);
  }

  if (destination.sheet2 == null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet2);
  }

  if (destination.sheet3 == null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet3);
  }

}
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
}
}
```

FIXED SCRIPT

```
     function cleanAllOld () {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('fileList');
  var numberFiles = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i=0; i<numberFiles; i++) {

// File to be cleaned
  var fileID = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numberFiles).getValues();
 Logger.log('fileID[i][0]: ' + fileID[i][0]);       
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i][0]);
  var sheet1 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of CALC');
  var sheet2 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Print');
  var sheet3 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Markbook');

 if (sheet1 === null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet1);
  }

  if (sheet2 === null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet2);
  }

  if (sheet3 === null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet3);
  } 

}
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message?  If so, what is the error message and line that it occurs on?  If there is no error message, what is the result?  Is part of the code running?  It looks like you are trying to delete sheets, not folders.

Comment: Hi Sandy, just got it to run through the code and it picked up the error at     var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i]); (Error message:Invalid argument: id (line 78, file "Code")) Sorry for the lack of clarity but I am looking at deleting the sheets from within certain spreadsheets (collected from a given drive folder.)

Comment: Sorry just realized I didn't comment properly @SandyGood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getValues()` method returns a two dimensional array.  You are getting an error msg from:

```
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i])
```

Try using:

```
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i][0])
```

Add a second index with a zero.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the redundancy. I had previously successfully run that part of the script independently (with a spreadsheet at a time.)

Comment: Thanks, that resolved that step but now I get the message ("Invalid argument: id") How can I determine where the offending line of code is?

Comment: In the VIEW menu, choose Execution Transcript.  At the bottom of the Log, it will state the error and the line that it occurred on.

Comment: For purposes of development, don't us the `try/catch`.  I think that will prevent the Execution Transcript from showing what line the error occurred on.

Comment: OK, I'm getting it on the same line (Updated to <<var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i][0]);>>Invalid argument: id (line 78, file "Code")) I have put an edited script up with the question to make it easier to follow.

Comment: Log the value of the id.  `Logger.log('fileID[i][0]: ' + fileID[i][0]);`  Is it a valid ID?

Comment: After looking at the logger it was only picking up every other line from the range (12 items total) and so by the time it reached the 7th item it drew a blank triggering the error. Why would that be?

Comment: Step through the code line by line with the debugger.  Read the troubleshooting guide at the following link:  [Google Documentation - breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: Found my error, I had put <var fileID = sheet.getRange(2+i, 1, numberFiles-1).getValues();> instead of <var fileID = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numberFiles).getValues();>

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue, I have bolded the corrected line below

```
  function cleanAllOld () {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('fileList');
  var numberFiles = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i=0; i<numberFiles; i++) {

// File to be cleaned
  **var fileID = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numberFiles).getValues();**
 Logger.log('fileID[i][0]: ' + fileID[i][0]);       
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID[i][0]);
  var sheet1 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of CALC');
  var sheet2 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Print');
  var sheet3 = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Markbook');

 if (sheet1 === null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet1);
  }

  if (sheet2 === null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet2);
  }

  if (sheet3 === null) {
  } else {
    destination.deleteSheet(sheet3);
  } 

}
}
```